# How to compare String Arrays with JUnit in Scala

Tags: java, arrays, string, scala, junit

I was trying to compare to String Arrays in a JUnit test suite in Scala using `assertArrayEquals`. It works fine for basic types like `Int` or `Boolean`, however it issues the following error when applying it to `String`:

> overloaded method value toString with alternatives: (x$1: Array[Object])String  (x$1: Array[Double])String  (x$1: Array[Float])String  (x$1: Array[Boolean])String  (x$1: Array[Byte])String  (x$1: Array[Char])String  (x$1: Array[Short])String  (x$1: Array[Int])String  (x$1: Array[Long])String cannot be applied to (Array[String])

This seems weird to me since using the same method in a Java environment works without a problem.
Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Hint: use **assertThat(actual, is(whatever))**. Works for almost everything.

Comment: Jep, works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. Looking forward to "work" with you again ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My "general" answer: one only needs *one* assert; and that is [**assertThat**](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(java.lang.String,%20T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)). That assert works with Hamcrest matchers, so typically you write down

```
assertThat(expected, is(whatever))
```

And using the wide range of existing hamcrest matchers, you immediately get "expected" results; even for collections and such things.

And if the standard means don't work; writing custom matchers is a straight forward task, too.

So, long story short: just use that assert that simply works.